# Send Name and Birthday to Watch using WatchConnectivity

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchconnectivity

I’m accessing a users Contacts to send the contact Name and Birthday from the iPhone to the AppleWatch. I have access to the Contacts and can display the data on the phone, but I’m having trouble sending the info with WatchConnectivity. I'm using the Ray Wenderlich book [WatchOS by Tutorials](https://store.raywenderlich.com/products/watchos-by-tutorials) as a guide but am still having trouble.

Here is what I have on the Phone side to set up Watch Connectivity in `AppDelegate.swift`.

```
// MARK:  Watch Connectivity
extension AppDelegate: WCSessionDelegate {

func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
    print("WC Session did become inactive.")
}

func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
    print("WC Session did deactivate.")
    WCSession.default().activate()
}


func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("WC Session activation failed with error:" + "\(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    print("Phone activated with state:" + "\(activationState.rawValue)")
}

func setUpWatchConnectivity() {
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session = WCSession.default()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
        }
    }

}
```

And this in `ViewController.swift`

```
// MARK Watch Connectivity

extension ViewController {


func sendNameAndBirthdayToWatch() {
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session = WCSession.default()
        if session.isWatchAppInstalled {
            let nameAndBirthday = ["name": nameLabel.text, "birthday": birthdayLabel.text]
            do {
                try session.updateApplicationContext(nameAndBirthday)
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
         }
     }
  }

}
```

I'm calling `sendNameAndBirthdayToWatch()` with a UIButton on the phone. As a prototype the phone currently displays the name and birthday on two separate labels pulled from the Contacts in the Xcode simulator so I at least know I'm getting the data.

On the watch in the `ExtensionDelegate.swift` I have.

```
// MARK: Watch Connectivity
extension ExtensionDelegate: WCSessionDelegate {

func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Activation failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    print("Watch activated with activation state: \(activationState.rawValue) ")
}

func setupWatchConnectivity() {
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session = WCSession.default()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
    if let name = applicationContext["name"] as? String, let birthday = applicationContext["birthday"] as? String {
        InterfaceController.sharedInterfaceController.updateWatchLabel(name: name, birthday: birthday)
    }
}
}
```

This is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong and/or how to move forward.

I'm calling `updateWatchLabel()` in the `InterfaceController.swift` on the watch, but I'm not seeing any results.

Thank you in advance for any help. I've been staring at this for a solid week and unfortunately the example project in the Wenderlich book is a bit too complicated for my understanding.

I'm using Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3.

Comment: Have you tried using real devices instead of the simulator to see if you have more success then?

Comment: @ccjensen I have and what I've noticed is that I don't get a message in the console that WatchConnectivity is activating on the Watch. I'm presently working on that.

Answer (score 1):

In time I answered my own question.

Here is the code on the phone in `ViewController.swift`. The code remains the same as in my original post in `AppDelegate.swift`.

```
    func sendMessageToWatch() {
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session = WCSession.default()
        if session.isWatchAppInstalled {
            do {
                let message = ["message": "A message as String"]
                try session.updateApplicationContext(message)
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }

        } else if session.isWatchAppInstalled == false {
            print("No watch app installed")
        }
    }
}
```

I am at the moment calling this function by pressing a UIButton on the phone. Then on the watch side in `InterfaceController.swift` for the receiving end. I basically moved the code from `ExtensionDelegate.swift` to `InterfaceController.swift`.

```
    // MARK: Watch Connectivity
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Activation failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    print("Watch activated with activation state: \(activationState.rawValue) ")
}


func setupWatchConnectivity() {
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let session  = WCSession.default()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
    let message = applicationContext["message"] as? String

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:  {
        self.label.setText(message)
    })

}
```